# How to merge a certain column of a dataframe to another?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with dates from 2003-01-01 ti 2017-06-30:

```
       dates
0     2003-01-01
1     2003-01-02
2     2003-01-03
3     2003-01-04
4     2003-01-05
5     2003-01-06
...
5284  2017-06-20
5285  2017-06-21
5286  2017-06-22
5287  2017-06-23
5288  2017-06-24
5289  2017-06-25
5290  2017-06-26
5291  2017-06-27
5292  2017-06-28
5293  2017-06-29
5294  2017-06-30
```

Now I have a second dataframe `dt2`

```
  just_dates  Counts
0  2003-01-02      1
1  2015-10-31      1
2  2015-11-01     14
3  2015-11-02     17
4  2015-11-03     11
5  2015-11-04      3
```

I want to write the counts of the dataframe `dt2` as a new column in `dates` if the certain date exist and if not a zero.
So my expected output is:

```
       dates       counts
0     2003-01-01     0
1     2003-01-02     1
2     2003-01-03     0
3     2003-01-04     0
4     2003-01-05     0
...
3523  2015-11-01     14
3524  2015-11-02     17
...
5293  2017-06-29     0
5294  2017-06-30     0
```

I tried something like this
`df['counts']=df['dates'].isin(out['just_dates']).astype(int)`
But this give me just ones and zeros if the date exists or not and I want to have the relative number in 'counts'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a merge with left join:

> “Left outer join produces a complete set of records from Table A, with
>   the matching records (where available) in Table B. If there is no
>   match, the right side will contain null.”

```
df = pd.merge(df, df2, how='left', left_on='dates', right_on='just_dates')
```

Since the left outer join will produce null/nan values, we must fill them with 0. We also want to remove the redundant column:

```
df['Counts'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['just_dates'], inplace=True)
```

with `inplace=True` to actually change the contents of the column.

Comment: And how can I add a new column counts to `df`? I don't see where I choose the column "Counts" from the dataframe "df2"

Comment: ok i used `df['counts']= df2['Counts'].fillna(0, inplace=True)` and it works. Thank you!

Comment: You must make sure you use the correct dataframe variables and count names

Comment: But in your code, where do I say: choose the column 'Counts' from df2?

Comment: You don't. The merge will add the 'Counts' column from df2 to df. Please check how the different merges work.

Comment: Forgot about that. updated the code with a drop column. On mobile so can't run code

Comment: I become a error 'counts' I think because there isn't a column 'counts' in df defined..

Comment: since you merged with df2, the column will be called `Counts`